# Google Chrome dmg wont eject after installation, even though it's not in use

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, dmg

I just bought a MacBook Air M1 (it's my first MacBook so im pretty new to the OS). I downloaded and installed Google chrome, however I'm trying to delete the dmg file but when I click eject or try to delete the file manually it says that is being used by Google Chrome and cannot be deleted, but I've closed google chrome already.

Any suggestions to what might be happening? Thanks! (also excuse my English, not my first language)

Comment: What happens when you Restart your MBA?

Comment: Maybe see what `lsof /Volumes/{whatever the chrome drive is called}` shows you. It'll list processes that have open files on that device. Did you close the Chrome window or actually exit the application?  Activity Monitor can tell you that, too. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still have this problem, but I tried switching my WiFi off and then ejecting the file and it works! Works for the other softwares I installed too.